# PHP / Linux Image Patterns

Tags: php, linux, gd

I am trying to find a way to overlay textures onto images of furniture. Similar to:

http://www.la-z-boy.com/Product/5767-1132/Collins-Living-Room-Sofa/

The only solution I can come up with is to create a Photoshop script to do this. The issue is there are 1000’s of furniture items and 1000’s of fabrics. We are talking 100k+ images to make this work. I was hoping someone knew of a program or function in PHP or Linux I could use to dynamically create these images.

Answer (score 0):

Is you have a proper mask for the models cut out, you can use `imagemagicks` on the server to add the pattern.

See more about the mask feature here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#mask